# How to recognize or avoid empty boost::function as std::function

Tags: c++11, boost

I'm currently working on a code using mostly boost but moving more and more to C++11 and it's std library.

There I had crash while passing an empty boost::function as a callback to a std::function:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   boost::function <void(void)> boost_f;
   std::function <void(void)> std_f;
   std::cout << "used " << (std_f!=nullptr) << " " << (!boost_f.empty()) << "\n";

   boost_f = boost::function<void(void)>();
   std_f = boost_f;
   std::cout << "used " << (std_f!=nullptr) << " " << (!boost_f.empty()) << "\n";

   if( std_f )
      std_f();
}
```

The std::function claims it has a valid target, but the empty boost::function throws an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call> >'
  what():  call to empty boost::function
```

Tested with gcc-6.3.1 and clang-4.0.

How could I avoid this problem? Could this be fixed so that an empty boost::function assigned to a std::function gives an empty std::function? Or could I check the std::function explicitly for an empty boost::function assigned to it?

Only avoiding the exception is not the intended solution because the function should behave differently dependent on the callback set or not (and it is often not set, so catching the exception should be avoided too).

Comment: I think you can't do the checking at assignment or initialization, as there is no hook or customization point to mutate the default behavior of `std::function` or `boost::function` with this regard. How about a helper function `boostFctOrEmpty(boost::function<...>&)`, however? This could return the function object if it's non-empty, or an empty `std::function` object otherwise.

Comment: These helper function would be required on caller side? In the real code the callbacks are set through a function and I'd like to avoid adapting the callers. One option is to overload the callback setter interface with std::function and boost:.function until all callers use std::function...

Comment: You can use a try-catch pair to catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: @eprom I considered catching too, but this would create too many obsolete exceptions (see my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
    if(std_f)
    {
        if( std_f.target_type()==typeid(boost::function<void(void)>))
        {
            auto boostF=std_f.target<boost::function<void(void)>>();
            if(boostF&&*boostF)
                std_f();
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"empty boost function"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
            std_f();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this really works and can be implemented efficiently at the function storing the callback.

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, if you don't use a third-party library that you can't modify, it's best to just use one of std::function and boost::function. Mixing them like you is equivalent to wrapping a callable object with two layers, so it will cause such problems.